How to set facebook au banner ads in 1 activity and it show in multiple Activity
I set this code in /res/layout/activity_main.xml
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/banner_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

And I also set in java class
private AdView adView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

adView = new AdView(this, "my_ads_code", AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);
LinearLayout adContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.banner_container);
adContainer.addView(adView);
adView.loadAd();

I use these codes in MainActivity. How do I use these banner ads in the second activity?

Make new layout file and add your ads code in that file than whenever you want to use that coode just write include and add your layout in that like this
  <include layout="@layout/layoutresourcefilename"/>

And for java file,
public class CommonUtils{
  private AdView adView;
  public static void showData(){
    adView = newAdView(this,"my_ads_code",AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);
    LinearLayoutadContainer=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.banner_container);
    adContainer.addView(adView);
    adView.loadAd();
  }
}

and when you want to use just write CommonUtils.showData();

What's wrong with me? see screenshot  https://i.ibb.co/y4dJSGc/ssss.jpg

just do one thing while calling function
LinearLayout adContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.banner_container);
CommonUtils.showData(ActivityName.this,adContainer);
then in your it looks like
public class CommonUtils{
private AdView adView;
public static void showData(ActivityName activity, LinearLayout adContainer){
adView = newAdView(activity,"my_ads_code",AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);
adContainer.addView(adView);
adView.loadAd();
}
}
